# Dynamically pass cell range using java POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, conditional-formatting

My requirement is I need to pass Cell Range dynamically for conditional formatting using Java POI.
I am referring code from below link but its not working because what to write for this cell.

```
String name = CellReference.convertNumToColString(cell.getColumnIndex());
String location = "$" + name + "$" + cell.getRowIndex() + ":$" + name + "$"
                  + (cell.getRowIndex() + 1);
CellRangeAddress[] regions = { CellRangeAddress.valueOf(location) };
```

[How to define dynamic cell range for Excel sheet using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480696/how-to-define-dynamic-cell-range-for-excel-sheet-using-java)